# nuget: specify dependency only for specific target framework

Tags: silverlight, .net-4.0, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers

I have the following situation:

- My library makes use of the **IObservable** interface, inluded in .NET4
- In SL5 it makes sense to reference **Rx.Main**, since it contains definitions of **IObservable** / **IObserver** with the extension methods working on exact those interfaces, which is the whole point.

Is it possible to specify in your Nuget package that only the SL5 version of the package has a dependency on RxMain?

```
My Nuget
  / net40 -> No dependencies
  / sl5 -> Rx.Main
```

It almost looks like it isn't, but then, what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible yet (there's a feature request for it http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/697). Best thing you can do for now is have 2 packages.

Comment: Fast-forward to sep/2012, this is now supported: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies_in_version_2.0_and_above